# what should I do? I already install my NetBeans on the desktop

Tags: installation

**This is a screenshot of my desktop. I can't download my Netbeans because it says "JDK 8 OR newer is required for......" but I already install my Java on the desktop. I don't know what is wrong can you please help me I also already added the path of my bin on advance settings, yet I still don't know what is wrong** 
[resourceful screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3Fst.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Just uninstall the version of Java you already have, and install a newer JDK. You can also just install the newer JDK, and direct NetBeans to this JDK version.
Good luck!